# Python script for RTU Modbus

Tags: python, modbus

I am working on a automation of my home using a raspberry pi 3B+

I bought a electronic energy meter MEMO4-M-MOD. 
https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/152f/0900766b8152f22b.pdf
To connect it to raspberry pi i bought a cable RS485/USB.

I am interested to read some values from the energy meter 
( exemple in the datasheet of the energy meter it says that the register adress of voltage is on the adress 2000(hexa)  )
i wrote this code

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import minimalmodbus
import serial


instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0',0) 
instrument.serial.port
instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600
instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
instrument.serial.parity =serial.PARITY_NONE
instrument.serial.stopbits = 1
instrument.serial.timeout = 0.05
instrument.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU

try:
    
    valeur= instrument.read_register(2000,1,3,False) 
    print(valeur) 
except IOError:
    print("no connection")
```

Problem I am facing here is it print no connection, so that make me think i use correctly the library.
Have you used this library?can you give me some advice to make that work?
 thank you so much

Comment: First of all - please remove "try" and "except" so that you can see the actual error it is throwing - report back what that error is.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import minimalmodbus
import serial

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0',1)
instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600
instrument.close_port_after_each_call = True

valeur = instrument.read_float(2000, functioncode=3, number_of_registers=2, byteorder=0)

print(valeur)
```

Connect your RS485 USB device to your pi and make sure that your pi can see it... check by running "dmesg | grep ttyUSB" you will get an output of most likely ttyUSB0, use whatever this is as your device address.

You also need to set modbus address of power meter, I set it to 1 above...

Your register is big endian, I checked official documentation here on returning a big endian double register value (classed as read_float): https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/internalminimalmodbus.html